# $f(x)=kx~(\text{mod }1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=kx~(\text{mod }1)\colon [0,1]\to [0,1], k\in\{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}.
$$

Let $\varepsilon >0$. I would like to understand why
$$
\max_{0\leq i\leq n-1}\lvert f^i(x)-f^i(y)\rvert < \varepsilon~\Leftrightarrow~\lvert x-y\rvert\leq \varepsilon k^{-n+1}~~(\text{ as points in }\mathbb{R}).
$$

Unfortunately I do not see how to prove this.

Comment: What does $f^i(x)$ mean? Does it mean $f^i(x) : = ix$?

Comment: I think it means $f^i(x)=(f\circ f\circ\ldots\circ f)(x)$, i- times

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the definition provided of $f^i = f\circ \cdots\circ f$ (where the composition is performed $i$ times) is correct, this is clearly not true. For any $k\geq 2$, consider $x = 0$ and $y = 1/k$. Then, $f^i(x) = f^i(y) = 0$ for all $i\geq 1$, so if we let $\epsilon > 1/k$, we will have $$\max_{0\leq i\leq n-1} \lvert f^i(x)-f^i(y)\rvert = 1/k < \epsilon$$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, but $$\lvert x-y\rvert\leq \frac{\epsilon}{k^{n-1}}$$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ would imply $x = y$.

Comment: I think the statement simply is that for the metric  $d(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert$, we have that the new defined metric $d_n(x,y):=\max_{0\leq i\leq n}d(f^i(x),f^i(y)$, we have that $d_n(x,y)<\varepsilon$ iff $\lvert x-y\rvert\leq \varepsilon k^{-n+1}$.  I think this is true?

Comment: No, it's not true, as I point out above. If that statement is true, then in my example, we should have $\lvert 1/k\rvert< \epsilon k^{-n+1}$ for all $n$, which is obviously false.